# How to get the parent container of a JWindow in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jwindow

I have one `JFrame` and calling a `JDialog` from that frame while initializing.  In the dialog have a `JButton`, when clicking on the button a new `JWindow` opens.

Can I fix the position of window in the main frame?  How to access the parent container (`JFrame` extended) from `JWindow`  extended class?

Comment: please add relevant code to your question

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you might be able to use [`JDialog#setLocationRelativeTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo(java.awt.Component)) and pass it the reference of the `JButton`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor(java.awt.Component)), if inside the `JWindow` class, refer it as `this`, if no, simply put object inside:

```
JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);

JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(myJWindow);
```

Comment: Can  I fix the window in first frame.