# How do I get the value of the focused "JFrame"?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe

I've been working on Java for the past 2 months and in my program I have one main `JFrame` and in that there are several `Jbutton`'s.

When I click on a `Jbutton` a small `JFrame` pops up where the title is the button name.

In each small (sub) `JFrame` there is text box to which I have assigned a `keyListener` to detect `ENTER` button.

The problem I'm facing is that I want to get the `Title String` of a particular small (sub) `JFrame` in which user has entered the text and then pressed the `ENTER` button.

Part of program is as below:

- `cltt` is a `JTextField`
- `[opnwinct]` is the array's index number
- `sendbutaction()` is another function that I'm calling

The problem is caused by the following code:

```
cltt[opnwinct].addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
      System.out.println(e.getTitle());
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I copy paste the code, but here is post my indentation and spaces got trimmed. Please consider the same.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
The information about mcve is particularly useful. Side note: for pop-up windows use [JOptionPane](https://alvinalexander.com/java/joptionpane-showinputdialog-examples)

Comment: See [How to get the parent container in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122731/how-to-get-the-parent-container-of-a-jwindow-in-swing) and [How do you get the JFrame title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041702/how-do-you-get-the-value-of-the-jframe-title)

Comment: @bhushanbapat `I copy paste the code, but here is post my indentation and spaces got trimmed.` - when you paste the code you need to select the code you just pasted and then click on the "{}" button to keep the formatting.

Comment: hello @camickr.... I got the query solved in the mean time.. but thanks for suggestion of clicking {}...